# Directional derivative

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

> what is the directional derivative of$ f(x,y)=xy+x^2$  at the point $(2,-1,1)$ in the direction $(1,3,-1)$?

So the unit vector is $\frac{(1,3,-1)}{\sqrt{11}}$, now we have to take the gradient of the function, but because $z=xy+x^2$ we get $((y+2x)\hat{i}+x\hat{j})$ multiplying by the unit vector and entering the point we get:

$((y+2x)\hat{i}+x\hat{j})\cdot\frac{(1,3,-1)}{\sqrt{11}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{11}}({y+2x}+{3x})$  placing $p=(2,-1,1)$ we get $\frac{9}{\sqrt{11}}$

is the following correct?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. Since $f\colon\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, you can only take directional derivatives of $f$ for directions that belong to $\mathbb R^2$. Also $f(2,-1) = 2$, so $(2,-1,1)$ is not part of the graph of $f$.

Comment: Yea that what I thought, thanks for the confirmation

Comment: If $z = xy+x^2$ then you would consider the surface $f(x,y,z)=0$ where $f(x,y,z)=xy+x^2-z$ and now your dot product will make sense.